# Laravel - Set model connection with Auth::user()

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

In my project every user has his/her database and I have defined the connection on config/database.php. So, in the model need to set the database connection.

```
// defines default database connection
protected $connection = Auth::user()->database;
```

I can't use this because it will throw an error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Can anyone help me with this please?

To store and show data, I use:

```
DB::connection(Auth::user()->database)->table(...
```

And works like a charm. Can someone help me with $connection to be ble to set it by a variable?

Regards

Comment: Can you set `$this->connection = Auth::user()->database` in your constructor?

Comment: Beware you might get into trouble when no user is logged in when querying.

Comment: @JeremyHarris, inside the controller, if I define __construct() with Auth::, gives error -- Trying to get property 'database' of non-object.

Comment: @Jerodev, the app ad every route protected by auth middleware, so, shouldn't be a problem ;) thanks!

Comment: How about your login route?

Comment: @Jerodev, Auth routes will use another connection, basically, the default. The CRUD operations is what I need to work out, since every user has its own database.

Comment: Look towards implementing https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionResolver.html

Comment: What about a custom middleware where you call `$user->setConnection($user->database)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem via middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $database)
{
    // check witch database connection to use
    switch ($database) {
        case 'self':
            // Set the User Database Connection
            DB::setDefaultConnection(Auth::user()->database);
            // Reconnect
            DB::reconnect();
            break;
        case 'main_db':
            // Set the User Database Connection
            DB::setDefaultConnection('main_db');
            // Reconnect
            DB::reconnect();
            break;
        default:
            // default action
            abort(403, 'Não está autorizado a aceder ao recurso solicitado.');
            break;
    }
    // next request...
    return $next($request);
}
```

And, in every controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // calls the middleware: SetDatabaseConnection
    $this->middleware('SetDatabaseConnection:self');
}
```

Thanks for the tips.